# Specify return type when value of input interface is specific value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-conditional-types

I have a function that takes an object as an argument. When a property of that input is a given value, I want to specify the return type as being one or the other. I assume this requires conditional types, but I'm struggling with the syntax to access the property of a given interface.

What I currently have is below:

```
enum FileAcl {
    private = 'private',
    public = 'public',
}

interface UploadOpts {
    someval: string;
    acl: FileAcl;
}

interface PrivateAclResponse {
    acl: FileAcl.private;
    key: string;
}

interface PublicAclResponse {
    acl: FileAcl.public;
    file: string;
}

const uploadFile = async (opts: UploadOpts):
    Promise<PublicAclResponse | PrivateAclResponse> => {
    const { acl } = opts;

    if (opts.acl === FileAcl.public) return { file: 'file', acl }

    return { key: 'key', acl }

}
```

I did try the following, but I'm clearly wrong so any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
enum FileAcl {
    private = 'private',
    public = 'public',
}

interface UploadOpts {
    someval: string;
    acl: FileAcl;
}

interface PrivateAclResponse {
    acl: FileAcl.private;
    key: string;
}

interface PublicAclResponse {
    acl: FileAcl.public;
    file: string;
}

// assuming here that ts can match the common properties
type PublicOrPrivate<T extends UploadOpts> = T extends PublicAclResponse
    ? PublicAclResponse
    : PrivateAclResponse;

const uploadFile = async (
    opts: UploadOpts
): Promise<PublicOrPrivate<UploadOpts>> => {
    const { acl } = opts;

    if (opts.acl === FileAcl.public) return { file: 'file', acl }

    return { key: 'key', acl }

}
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use a [Conditional Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). But additionally a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) parameter is needed for the condition. Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't seem to be able to narrow `opts` to either `PublicAclResponse` or `PrivateAclResponse` which means we need to [assert the return type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
const uploadFile = async <
  T extends UploadOpts,
  R = T["acl"] extends FileAcl.public
    ? PublicAclResponse
    : PrivateAclResponse
>(
  opts: T
): Promise<R> => {
  const {acl} = opts;

  if (opts["acl"] === FileAcl.public) return {file: "", acl} as R;

  return {key: "key", acl} as R;
};

const publicResponse = uploadFile({ // Promise<PublicAclResponse>
  acl: FileAcl.public,
  someval: ""
});

const privateResponse = uploadFile({ // Promise<PrivateAclResponse>
  acl: FileAcl.private,
  someval: ""
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglgG2AQQMYKgbwLACgpQAOATnAG4CGALsFALxQBEJ51wjANHgYWAEYI4qek14ChjPAF88eOCBrEAZhVS0AqoQQB7CgBMA8oSoBnLNygntEYJQQAuS1VIgA5gG4Lqh7EQp0nrgyuHIKwMqqtAAKpJQ0aAgASsAmhNogJrQ4%20FDejvBICQB0LHHAgQQA1sAAno4mzvIe0rK48ooqalBR-IKoCcmp6ZnmOXm%20heglvUIVUEp%209Y1ugcF4qMNUUGBaunoFtAwUJjUgwgA8FgAqUMAAHjQgemaaOvpGplw5iSJXANqMbyMAC6tweoGeE38CGm4lQFgIAH5ujN%20uhBmkMsAEVBHDFWPF0SlMZk8AA%20AAUFm0xhMjiueAAlHjiNY4JlzokyfRudkCBsMltMN4pCIaaZAhY4EooBTxSYAUDQXQVVDimI%20oyoMRgFQwMQQFgFkhHIxOLl0KLjlBEpKcjq9QasNU6kwXeaRbkzLbpHaBQ0iKiMcNDttdvoDhS%20VAAPQxqAAPURXnQ%20T86tRXwIVhsdlNkiCjLt602RFibGDWJEOze%20z8UYsccTybGqbVU1KbCzlmstgoPjN0iLeCAA)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. This has worked a charm!